# iOS: I have an error message 'Address of property expression requested'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, pointers, memory

I have a problem with the code lines:

```
memset(&array->objects[array->count] & memmove(&array->objects[objectIndex + 1UL]
```

Here is the all code for info:

```
if(!((array != NULL) && (array->objects != NULL) && (objectIndex <= array->count) && (newObject != NULL))) { [newObject autorelease]; return; }
  if((array->count + 1UL) >= array->capacity) {
    id *newObjects = NULL;
    if((newObjects = (id *)realloc(array->objects, sizeof(id) * (array->capacity + 16UL))) == NULL) { [NSException raise:NSMallocException format:@"Unable to resize objects array."]; }
      array->objects = *newObjects;
    array->capacity += 16UL;
    memset(&array->objects[array->count], 0, sizeof(id) * (array->capacity - array->count));
  }
  array->count++;
  if((objectIndex + 1UL) < array->count) { memmove(&array->objects[objectIndex + 1UL], &array->objects[objectIndex], sizeof(id) * ((array->count - 1UL) - objectIndex)); array->objects[objectIndex] = NULL; }
  array->objects[objectIndex] = newObject;
```

I really have no idea about that problem...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is complaining that you are trying to get an address pointer to an object which is a class property. To some extent Objective C tries to shy use of its properties and objects away from C language use.  I'd suggest copying the data from your object into some type of C structure, and using that to copy.